# Is it possible to use Vista locally and remotely at the same time?

Tags: windows-vista, remote-desktop

Using Windows Vista Business, is it possible to have a user sitting at the machine using it, and another user simultaneously logged into a different user account over remote desktop?

If so, how?

Comment: 2 different user accounts running at the same time on the same machine?

Comment: So basically you want to turn Vista into an old Unix style machine?

Comment: @echo yes.  @Lucas no I'm mostly just curious.

Comment: its hard enough getting Vista to be remotely usable let alone usable remotely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows Vista Business license limits the number of users able to use the OS at a single time to 1.  For this reason, any time you try to log in remotely, it automatically logs out the local user.  If you want to allow multiple users to log in via RDP you will need [Terminal Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892075%28VS.85%29.aspx) on a server machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing and using any of the VNC family of software.

It allows a remote user to tap into the pc, and control the mouse, keyboard, and see the screen simultaneously as a local user.

I personally always used RealVNC, but TightVNC, and UltraVNC are all excellent choices.

[VNC via wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)

Comment: OP is probably looking for the local and the remote to be able to control the computer at the same time without conflicting or overriding one another.

Answer (score 1):

Nativity Windows Vista does not allow for Concurrent sessions. So the answer is No you cant log in to the physical machine and a Remote desktop from another machine with different accounts. However, this being the world of Microsoft there are those who have figured out how to do this, see this [artical](http://www.missingremote.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1220&Itemid=224).

Answer (score 0):

There are ways, I will not link them here, but out of the box, that version of windows only supports one RDP connection at a time. The Server OSs (Server 2003, Server 2008) allow multiple, concurrent connections.